# JProfiler JDBC profiling - NullPointerException in OraclePreparedStatement

Tags: jprofiler

I'm attempting to profile Oracle JDBC connections. Oracle server is 11XE, JDBC file - ojdbc6.jar., JProfiler 8.0.2

As soon as portion of my code attempts to make prepared statement, I'm getting following error...

Exception in thread "Controller Thread 0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.(OraclePreparedStatement.java:407)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.(T4CPreparedStatement.java:29)
2014-01-14 17:59:58,545 Controller INFO ControllerThread - runApplication() Exit Thread Controller Thread 0
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.allocatePreparedStatement(T4CDriverExtension.java:67)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3575)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:3461)

Any thoughts as to how to resolve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com with a small test case.

Comment: Submitted. I've provided basic JUnit test with use of PreparedStatement to retrieve data from Oracle DB. Once I enable JDBC profiling I get NullPointerException in ....<br/>
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.<init>(OraclePreparedStatement.java:404)<br/> The error goes away once JDBC profiling is disabled in the session.